# What setup is need to compile rpy2 on Windows?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I've been able to install `rpy2` v2.0.8 from the `.msi` from source forge, but I'd like to use the latest version that includes the packages code, i.e. `v2.1.9`.

I'm attempting to compile rpy2 in windows (python `2.6.6`).

CL is complaining because `LibExtern` is being defined as `extern` and as `declspec` in different place.

`gcc` and `c++` can't compile without errors either.

I'm assuming this compiles ok on unix and that all I'm missing is some config (prob environment variables), since I can't believe it would have been released in a non-compilable form.

Any anyone point me in the right direction pls?

Many thx

DM

Comment: 2.1 is not supported on Windows; see http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.1/html/overview.html#microsoft-s-windows-precompiled-binaries

Comment: Have you considered PypeR?  I haven't tried it yet.  I believe [this is its homepage](http://www.webarray.org/softwares/PypeR/), and [this is an article about it](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v35/c02/paper), comparing it to Rpy and Rpy2.  (I've also posted this to another question about Rpy2 & Windows.  It seems others have the same interest.)

Comment: rpy2 binaries are available on [gohlke's page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2)

Comment: Thx really appreciate you posting that

Comment: Thanks @seumas you've saved me (probably a lot of) time

Comment: I tried getting this to build for a while, and there are much deeper issues than config files - e.g., R's file directory has been shifted around since the last update.  Building this will probably take substantial effort.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to download it from [this site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2). It has all the popular repositories that need to be compiled in order to work. Its basically a group Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages by Christoph Gohlke at The Laboratory for Fluorescence Dynamics, University of California, Irvine.

I've given you the link to the latest version of `rpy2`, and there are versions for every type of Python. Please note that you will need R installed. Download the version for 2.7, it *should* work for 2.6.6, but if it does not, then update your Python 2.7.5.

However, if you are still keen on *actually* compiling the binaries, then you will need to give me the error messages and the tracebacks, as otherwise, one cannot know for sure what your exact problems are.